# How is Chainlink decentralized?

Tags: contract-design, ethereumjs, oracles, decentralization, chainlink

I believe one of the main criticisms of chainlink is that it is not decentralized enough, adding more nodes would be a big step in a positive direction. When I pull data through a node, that node could be corrupt and ruin my smart contract, so what gives?

Answer (score 2):

Saying Chainlink is "not decentralized enough" is a lot like saying "a tree is not a forest enough".

Chainlink is a framework for connecting off-chain data to smart contracts in a decentralized manner. In the same sense that one Ethereum node is a part of the whole decentralized ecosystem, one Chainlink node is apart of the whole Chainlink ecosystem.

You can build an application using as many chainlink nodes as you like, right now there are over 100 listed on [market.link](https://market.link/nodes/ee1d7bc5-b64c-418c-bad4-bfd5f9a570e3), and you can build your system accordingly.

If you'd like an out-of-the-box solution, you can use [reference contracts](https://docs.chain.link/docs/using-chainlink-reference-contracts) which are a solution for those who want a pre-packaged decentralized solution. You can of course, use this alone, or as a starting point for a more decentralized application. These have 7 - 21 nodes each, and are constantly being improved.